# EventSource for fixed seconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I'm newbie to the feature of EventSource in javascript. As per my understanding the eventsource calls the api with stream content and gets the updates of data automatically without making any further calls. But I'm planning to make if possible to stop listening the response after 10 seconds from the EventSource. For Example in the below URL we can find the EventSource example, I want it to get stopped listening/fetching after 10 seconds.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`EventSource.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource/close) method and call it in a `setTimeout()` such as follows (adapted from the linked W3Schools code):

```js
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  const source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
  };
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    source.close();
    console.log("connection closed");
  }, 10000)
  
} else {
  console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...");
}
```

Comment: setTimeout behaves like Synchronous style right ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? JS does not get stuck on that line for 10 seconds like `sleep` where it cannot execute any other line, if that is what you're asking. It just calls the function you pass it as the first argument after the time specified in the second argument in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you got the point. Can we make the EventSource to behave like Sychronous execution ? (means like waiting for 10 seconds and moving to next line while compiling)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That's usually not a good idea and there are better methods to deal with asynchronous processes such as async/await.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy Yes, you could wrap that whole block of code in a Promise (google for how to do this), and do the Promise `resolve()` immediately after you do `source.close()`.  It seems a bit convoluted: it might make sense if you don't control the server-side, and SSE is the only way they provide data, I suppose.